App scale looks zoomed on physical device
Hey guys i need some help.
I'm fairly new to android studio but something doesn't seem right.
In the design window and on an emulated S24 Ultra, the display looks like this:
enter image description here
However, when i put that app on my actual S24 device, the elements look massively zoomed in
I have checked that there no screen zoom, no font size increase (even though i have used SP instead of DP)
I'm so confused, any help would be appreciated.
Heres the XML code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.064" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="@string/check_box"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioGroupText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70sp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_button1"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_button2"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_button3"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="53sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:text="@string/nextActivity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Again, not really sure what the issue is, I've been trying to figure it out for about an hour now!
